# Basic derived class member override. Challenge Activity 11.3

Tags: c++

I have a challenge for the school that states

Define a member function `PrintAll()` for `class PetData` that prints output as follows. Hint: Make use of the base class's `PrintAll()` function.
**Name: Fluffy, Age: 5, ID: 4444**

Then they give me the code below with a small snippet that I can alter. Between
`// FIXME: Add PrintAll()` member function
and
`/* Your solution goes here  */`
is the code I added but I'm not getting the correct result.

**MyCode**

```cpp
// FIXME: Add PrintAll() member function
void PrintAll() {
    AnimalData data;
    data.PrintAll();
    cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
}
/* Your solution goes here  */
```

**Full Code**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class AnimalData {
public:
   void SetName(string givenName) {
      fullName = givenName;
   };
   void SetAge(int numYears) {
      ageYears = numYears;
   };
   // Other parts omitted

   void PrintAll() {
      cout << "Name: "  << fullName;
      cout << ", Age: " << ageYears;
   };

private:
   int    ageYears;
   string fullName;
};

class PetData: public AnimalData {
public:
   void SetID(int petID) {
      idNum = petID;
   };

   // FIXME: Add PrintAll() member function
   void PrintAll(){
      AnimalData data;
      data.PrintAll();
      cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
      }
   /* Your solution goes here  */

private:
   int idNum;
};

int main() {
   PetData userPet;

   userPet.SetName("Fluffy");
   userPet.SetAge (5);
   userPet.SetID  (4444);
   userPet.PrintAll();
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

**Results I'm getting**
Name: , Age: -502747520, ID: 4444

**Results I want**
Name: Fluffy, Age: 5, ID: 4444

Comment: `AnimalData data; data.PrintAll();` -> `AnimalData::PrintAll();`?

Comment: Please let your teacher know that he has to learn how to give proper names to functions, variables, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in

```
void PrintAll(){
    AnimalData data;
    data.PrintAll();
    cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
}
```

`AnimalData data;` creates a new, default-initialized `AnimalData` that is entirely separate from the `AnimalData` that is part of the current `PetData`. Since you want to use the `AnimalData` you already have, discard this line and remove `data` from the next. This is where things can go very wrong, so I'm going to skip directly to the correct answer: To get the `PrintData` function for `AnimalData`, you need to be explicit:

```
void PrintAll(){
    AnimalData::PrintAll();
    cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
}
```

## Why You Cannot Simply Remove `data`

If you remove the object to invoke `PrintAll` on, `data`,

```
void PrintAll(){
    PrintAll();
    cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
}
```

`this` is assumed. `this` is a `PetData`, and for `PetData` the best match for the `PrintAll` function is the current function. The result is infinite [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

The real lesson to be learned here is to be careful when re-using an identifier. In this case, `PetData::PrintAll` shadows `AnimalData::PrintAll`, replacing it inside `PetData`. The function is not `virtual`, and you do not want `virtual` in this case, so you do not get an override. You can easily and accidentally do this with functions and variables, leading to confusion about which one is being used by the program.

## A (possibly) Better Way to Structure This Program

Take advantage of both inheritance and polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class AnimalData
{
public:
    virtual ~AnimalData() {}; // with polymorphism you must make sure the 
                              // correct destructor is always called.
                              // Derived classes will override this 
                              // destructor whether you explicitly define 
                              // them or not. 
    void SetName(string givenName)
    {
        fullName = givenName;
    }
    void SetAge(int numYears)
    {
        ageYears = numYears;
    }

    // virtual function. Derived classes can, but do not have to, replace 
    // this function with a version better suited to the derived class
    virtual void PrintAll()
    {
        cout << "Name: " << fullName;
        cout << ", Age: " << ageYears;
    }

private:
    int ageYears;
    string fullName;
};

class PetData: public AnimalData
{
public:
    void SetID(int petID)
    {
        idNum = petID;
    }

    // Replacing virtual function. Note if the base class function is 
    // virtual, then child class overrides are automatically virtual
    void PrintAll() override // override keyword notifies with a compiler 
                             // error if the function does NOT override when 
                             // it should.
    {
        AnimalData::PrintAll(); // call base class version for basic data
        cout << ", ID: " << idNum; // adding derived class-specific stuff
    }

private:
    int idNum;
};

// can add WildData here to handle wild animals.

int main()
{
    PetData userPet;

    userPet.SetName("Fluffy");
    userPet.SetAge(5);
    userPet.SetID(4444);
    userPet.PrintAll();
    cout << endl;

    // add an vanilla animal for demo
    AnimalData generic;
    generic.SetName("Fang");
    generic.SetAge(7);
    generic.PrintAll();
    cout << endl;

    // demonstrate polymorphism
    AnimalData * ptr = & generic;
    ptr->PrintAll();
    cout << endl;

    ptr = & userPet;
    ptr->PrintAll(); // runtime calls the correct PrintAll function
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know that when you give people false (as in incorrect) statement as a first thing, and than debunk it, people forget the debunk, but just remember the first thing? (I mean, you give the incorrect infinite recursion solution first, and I am pretty sure it is going to stuck). It is better to put it in the end of the answer, explaining why this wouldn't work.

Comment: @SergeyA Agreed and fixed.

Comment: This is such a useful explanation, thank you SO much

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a small misunderstanding about how to invoke methods of the superclass AnimalData in PetData:

```
void PrintAll(){
      AnimalData data;
      data.PrintAll();
      cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
      }
```

This creates a new instance of the class AnimalData, and invokes PrintAll() on that object. Because the fullName and ageYears aren't initialised in this new object, you get the unexpected output. To invoke the same method of the superclass, the syntax is `Superclass::Methodname()`. So the correct version of `AnimalData::PrintAll()` is as follows:

```
void PrintAll(){
      AnimalData::PrintAll();
      cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem.

```
void PrintAll(){
  AnimalData data;
  data.PrintAll();
  cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
  }
```

This function creates a new object of class `AnimalData` (which will be constructed according to the default constructor) and then calls the `AnimalData::PrintAll` method on that object. What you wanted to do was call the `AnimalData::PrintAll` method on *this* object.

```
void PrintAll(){
  AnimalData::PrintAll(); // call base class method
  cout << ", ID: " << idNum;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So this one was alot simpler than I thought. It's really a matter of calling the printAll method from PetData, and appending the ID num.

```
public void printAll(){
    super.printAll();
    System.out.print(", ID: " + idNum);
}
```